# make html image area ‘coord’ blinking or glow …

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, effects

i trying to make html image `<area coord tag` more clear to viewer. any javascript sample to make those coordinate blinking effect or similar as long as it each coord is clear to viewer?

p/s: problem with paste < area .that why you didn't see the full of my message.sorry repost

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested this as i don't have time right now but you should be able to make it stand out just with CSS, something like this:

```
area {
    filter:Glow(color=#00FF00,strength=4);
    text-decoration: blink;
}
```

Comment: i prefer your techinque. but i tried it doesnt work . do you have reference page i can read on ?   i'm using IE

Comment: after testing in firefox, area tags to not seem to benefit from any css so I'm not sure this is applicable.

Comment: Jonathan, it's ok. my question is, does the css tag that you put work in internet explorer? I tried and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Two slutions: one, overlay another image. The overlay image would be transparent except for the region you want to highlight, and with opacity set low enough to still see what is behind it. And two, use the real image as the background image to the aforementioned 'overlay' image (the overlay image must have the overlay region already be translucent instead of using css).

e.g. (version one)

```
<span class='image_container'>
    <img id='base_image' src='base.png' >
    <img id='overlay_image' src='overlayimage.png' usemap='#yourmaphere'>
    <map name='yourmaphere'>
    ...
    </map>
</span>

.image_container {
    position:relative;
}

#overlay_image {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    /* text-decoration: blink; */ /*optional*/
}
```

e.g. (version two)

```
<img id='base_image' src='overlayimage.png' usemap='#yourmaphere'>
<map name='yourmaphere'>
...
</map>

#base_image {
    background: transparent url(base.png) no-repeat scroll top left;
}
```

Comment: i prefer the technique of using css directly . ur technique sound promising as well